# Xamarin Studio - Storyboard looses all views but Document Outline shows them

Tags: xamarin.ios, storyboard, designer

I am starting to learn about Xamarin/IOS and I am trying a very simple example to use storyboard designer to add views.  I added 2 labels, a button, a switch and a slider and run it in emulator and all works as expected.  But then when I got back to my storyboard designer, none of the view was showing there anymore but Document Outline was showing them properly as per attached screenshot.  How do I get them show in design view?
[image]

They show when I run app in simulator and they were showing properly in designer as well when I added them initially
[image]

Comment: You have 2 storyboards in your Project `Main.Storyboard` and `LaunchScreen.Storyboard` . Which one have you set as active?

Comment: main.storyboard is the only one I am working on and that is where I added controls.

Comment: can you open the storyboard with XCode by right clicking the storyboard and selecting XCode. See if XCode shows your interface correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is another strange issue with Xamarin Studio.  I often find that it will not do what it is supposed to do and that restarting like explained here [Xamarin.iOS Designer - Creating Action segue not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40859517/xamarin-ios-designer-creating-action-segue-not-working?noredirect=1#comment68979912_40859517) often solves the issue.
Completely unrelated issue, but restarting helped in both cases.