# Xamarin.iOS Designer - Creating Action segue not working

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, segue

I am trying to add action segue by dragging a button on one screen to another in Xamarin Studio on Mac.  According to instruction provided by Xamarin university, this should create action segue.  My exact steps are

1. Click on Control key
2. Select button on 1st screen
3. Drag it to the 2nd screen
4. Release mouse and Control key

This should show a little popup prompting you to select type of segue (Push, Modal, or Custom).  In my case, the popup shows very briefly, so I have no time to select the type.

Comment: Are you able to get it working at all by slightly delaying release of either the control key or mouse? Out of curiosity, could you provide your version information from Xamarin Studio > About Xamarin Studio > Show Details > Copy Information [button]?

Comment: I have tried delaying, still same but I just posted my answer to this below.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that after restarting Xamarin Studio, I was able to get the popup stay so I can make my selection.  I have noticed that Xamarin Studion seem to have strange issues like this and the solution is often to close solution, quit Xamarin studio, restart it, reopen solution and try again.

Comment: I tried this solution but it did not work for me. Instead, I opened the Main Storyboard on XCode Interface Builder and from there create the segue and save. Go back to Xamarin or Visual Studio for Mac (I have both community version) and close the Solution. Open again the solution and voila I could now see the segue arrow. This is a bug that I don't know if Microsoft is even aware about, since it's almost 8 months when you posted this, and it is still a problem as of posting. Kind of sad, huh?

Answer (score 1):

Try use XCode for for modifying storyboard. I always use XCode for editing storyboard and placing my layout and after that name my control using Xamarin Studio by using Document Outline

Comment: This one works for me but unfortunately, it is not efficient since you have to open and close applications in order to see the changes. Microsoft should have corrected this seemingly simple bug.

Comment: yes it's not efficient but i got many hour save because it smoother to edit storyboard in xcode :D